# Maximum recursive updates exceeded, only on iOS in a specific component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 app which is giving me multiple errors only when I mount a specific component within my generic modal component. On desktop across browsers I get zero errors and everything works as expected. On iOS (using desktop Safari connected locally to capture console logs) it shows the log below, along with a few other "Maximum recursive updates..." from other components (which have nothing to do with the modal or it's inner template).

I've checked every single component that is listed in the error below (`"at~"`) and every other component that is used in that modal template (it's only one template that breaks) and NONE of them are using a `mounted` hook, so the "Unhandled exception during mounted hook" doesn't make any sense.

I know this is not much to go on, but has anyone else seen this recursive error happen only in certain components and only in iOS before?

In addition to the above, I've double checked all logic for any recursive issues and have found none. And, if there really were some, I would assume they would show up on desktop as well, not only on iOS.

Pretty stumped here, friends.

[image: Log from iPad]

Comment: Try commenting some parts of your code to see which one is concerned.

Comment: I don't think anything can be done for the question in its current state. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It could at least expose some potentially suspicious spots. Generally Safari shouldn't behave very different, also the version matters but you didn't specify it. You could try to debug this with Webkit browser which version corresponds to the one in Safari, e.g. Playwright's webkit engine.